# How to prevent my css rule to be overridden by normalise css in reactjs/jsx?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a very simple react component

```
class UpgradeContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.msg}>
            <div className={styles['msg-container']}>
              <h3 className={`${styles.title} highlight-color`}>
                Big Header
              </h3>
              <div className={`${styles.description} alternate-color`}>
                  Small text
                  <br />
                  Some more small text
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is the relevant css

```
.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
.description {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

And here is the DOM output from above component

[image]

It is reproduced as text here:

```
    <div class="mRMOZryRtlFUx_NHlt1WD" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1">
        <h3 class="_2s6iXRZlq-nQwIsDADWnwU highlight-color" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.0">
Big Header</h3>
         <div class="_1pFak-xR0a8YH6UtvoeloF alternate-color" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.1">
          <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.1.0">Small text</span>
           <br data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.1.1">
          <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.1.2">Some more small text</span></div></div>
```

As you can see, reactjs has added a couple of `<span/>` to wrap the small text

I expect the title text (`Big Header`) to be much larger than the description text (`small text` and `some more small text`).

The output however looks something like this:

[image]

It is because reactjs, for some reason, addd a span to wrap around the text `small text` and `some more small text` ( data-reactid ".0.1.0.0.0.1.1.0" and ".0.1.0.0.0.1.1.2" respectively)

When I checked the style I found that the styles of these `span` elements are overridden by the following css rules

[image]

I am really puzzled by it because I did not define these rules myself.

So I click on the `<style>...</style>` and it takes me to [image]

I want to know how I can effectively override these css rules?

The end result I want is:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure those styles are actually coming from normalize.css? Looking at the [github link in your picture](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) it doesn't actually show any of those styles. Is it possible the styles are being injected after the normalize.css styles? Also in my opinion, I think it'd be a lot cleaner if you didn't use a `<br/>` to create a space -- rather just use two divs to surround both the first and second text of display block and they will separate themselves on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

1. **If you're using 'Normalize.css'!** 
   A Solution for this problem is to keep your main css file 'style.css' in the bottom. At least below normalize.css.
2. **In case you're using Bootstrap,**
   Straight from the Bootstrap Official Website , "For improved cross-browser rendering, we use Normalize.css, a project by Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal."
   Solution for this problem is to keep your main css file 'style.css' in the bottom. At least below bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue like yours, and My solution was to import the Bootstrap style at the top of the app.tsx file. The reason for this is that it prevents Bootstrap CSS from being overridden by other styles in your application, it work for me